# Magento 2 custom grid column sort order

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, sort

I made a custom grid in Magento admin using the UI Component. All is working fine, besides the order of the columns that are not showing right.
[image]

- as you can see the action column is right at the beginning and the selected one is at the end
- when I created the columns in XML I took into consideration the `sortOrder` attribute for each column, but somehow the order is not the one that I set to be

The code from the `listing.xml` is the following

```
<columns name="inactive_columns" class="Module\MyModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inactive_listing.inactive_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">inactive_listing.inactive_listing.inactive_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inactive_listing.inactive_listing.inactive_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inactive_listing.inactive_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="firstname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Firstname</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="lastname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lastname</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Cacat</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="group_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="billing_telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Since</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="last_visit_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Logged In</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_in">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Created in</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="kpi_views_customer">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Kpi Views</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_membership">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Membership</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_access">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Access</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">222</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

and the class Module\MyModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns is

```
class Columns extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns
{

/**
 * @var \KPIs\CustomerReports\Model\Customer\Attribute\Repository\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
 */
protected $attributeRepository;

protected $manageAttributes;

/** @var int */
protected $columnSortOrder;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    ColumnFactory $columnFactory,
    AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
    ManageAttributes $manageAttributes,
    InlineEditUpdater $inlineEditor,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    $this->columnFactory = $columnFactory;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->manageAttributes = $manageAttributes;
    $this->inlineEditUpdater = $inlineEditor;
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    $customerAccessOptions = $this->attributeRepository->get(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, "customer_access")->getOptions();
    $customerMembershipOptions = $this->attributeRepository->get(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, "customer_membership")->getOptions();
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item["customer_access"])) {
                $item["customer_access"][0] = $customerAccessOptions[$item["customer_access"][0]]->getLabel();
            }
            if (isset($item["customer_membership"])) {
                $item["customer_membership"] = $customerMembershipOptions[$item["customer_membership"][0]]->getLabel();
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
}
```

- as you can see, in the class I don't do anything sortOrder related :), so it should be the default behavior
- also, the action and selection columns cannot be dragged and dropped (as far as I saw)

Does anyone have any idea how can I sort the columns from XML or the code?
The action should be the last column and the selection the first one.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Try to drag& drop column in grid

Comment: I tried that already, it's not working with action and selection columns

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this solution

1. Use below line to sort the column in grid.

   ```
   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
   ```
2. Open you database table **ui_bookmark**.
3. Search the name of your uiComponent from **namespce** column of
   **ui_bookmark table**. You can check uiComponent name from respective layout xml. below is just an example path.

   ```
   /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/module__controller_index.xml
   ```
4. Now delete the records that you find from **ui_bookmark** table.
5. Clear the cache

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:flush

   php bin/magento cache:clean
   ```

Thats all. Enjoy!

Comment: yep, that's the correct answer. Thx! :)

Comment: Works, but would be nice to know how to refresh it without direct database manipulation.

Comment: this works like mint :)

Comment: Admin logout/login can refresh its order if it is set properly in coding.

Comment: this is working superb... :)

Comment: Perfect answer..!!!

Answer (score 6):

Columns order for ui grid in Magento2 being stored in table `ui_bookmark`

For column `namespace` equal you grid name and identifier = `current` you should change `config` column value. You can find columns order there in every end of row, parameter "positions":{}

Comment: Really help full for me! It is working solution. I have delete both current and default view so now it working fine as i want.

Answer (score 4):

## ✅ You may explicitly set a `sortOrder` attribute on the XML `<column>` element.

Like so:

```
<column name="object_id" sortOrder="10">
```

###### Alternatively

Simply do not set a `sortOrder` value; the column order is implied by the order in which they are listed in the UI Component's XML.

> *You just write them in the order you want them to appear.*

---

## Here's my working example:

> **Note**: *I'm using what seems to be a newer (or older ) Magento XML definition schema for this than what the other answers are showing.*

###### `./view/adminhtml/ui_component/[your_component]_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">
    <columns name="object_listing_columns">
        <column name="object_id" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="is_active" sortOrder="20" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Is Active</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="store_id" sortOrder="30" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

---

## Cleaning the database's `ui_bookmark` table

Yes, like the other answers here, if you re-order `<column>`s in the UI Component's XML, you need to delete the database's `ui_bookmark` table entries that correspond to your module's `ui_bookmark`.`namespace`.

**You have to do this manually** with a database management tool of your choice.

The `ui_bookmark`.`namespace` value to remove will match what is defined your *layout* `.xml` files within the element `<uiComponent name="..."/>`:

###### `./view/adminhtml/layout/[module_name]_[controller_name]_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <uiComponent name="my_object_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> The database values you remove here are regenerated the next time the admin page is visited.

---

## ♻️  Ah yes, Cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Comment: Kudos for mentioning `ui_bookmark` cleanup - it is not the most apparent part of admin UI grids.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check first Your "module.xml" 
and find the code. 
example :

And check the order of your module must be loaded after or before the order is depend on module load order or make sure your module load as per your requirement.

you can check your module load order etc->config.xml file.